# Is there any websites full of practical examples from basic to advanced Excel VBA, as I am interested in learning Excel VBA through examples?

Tags: excel, vba

Any websites that will teach me Excelvba along with examples rather giving tool explaination not usage of it in practical scenarios. Please your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This [Wise Owl Tutorial series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5) seems fairly good, and has some practical aspects, I believe the tutor uses a number of practical scenarios and goes from beginner techniques of VBA to advanced.

One of the best ways I found to learn when first starting out is the record macro button. Although this won't give you perfect code, it can reveal plenty of the ways VBA interacts with Excel. If you get stuck on how to (for example) filter a pivot table in VBA, then you can just click record, do the action manually, click stop and the VBA code will be written for you! However, as mentioned, this won't be perfect, particularly because it will use things like "activate" and "select" (and those are really bad).

If you want to apply it to something you yourself have done, then as well as learning the basics, your best option is to just search on Google for your needs, as you'll probably find that someone has already asked a question you have and most of the code is done.

Everyone has a different way of learning though, so you will probably need to try a few things before you find what is right for you. There isn't a quick and easy path to learning VBA really, you've just got to get in there and do it. I also wouldn't worry about having perfect code at first (I sure did when I started learning how to program), as you should pick up best practices naturally, focus on getting an understanding and making things work first, and over time you'll become a lot better.

Comment: Great answer - I'll point to this when the question gets asked again, as it surely will.

Comment: I agree with @Clusks. And would add that, for me at least, almost as important as learning VBA is to learn "how to ask" and google that. How to ask: very pointed questions, stripped down to the essential. That way usually helps me to get clear what I **really** want to achieve (since many times that was the main problem). Good: How to delete a specific element in VBA array. Bad: How to generate a weekly report.